# The JS code doing nothing

Tags: ajax

What's wrong in this code? It's doing nothing, but Firebug give only one error:
"HTML-document does not contain an encoding declaration characters. If the document contains characters that are not in the range of US-ASCII, in some configurations, the browser will be displayed in the document garbled text. The character encoding of the page should be declared in the document or in the communication protocol.". This situation with all the sites.

`
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({

```
url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797",

type: "POST",

dataType: "text",

success: function(data) {

  $(".results").html(data);

},

error: function(e, xhr, data) {

  $(".results").html(data);

}
```

});

});
`

Comment: It seems like that website is not allowing CORS

Comment: Does that website allow for jsonp?

Comment: The page successfully work in IE, but not work in Chrome and Firefox.